# Convert EF 6 to .net Core when ObjectResult does not exist anymore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am needing to convert from EF6 to .net core 2.2.x  and I have been searching but I don't see how to convert some of this code from possibly EDMX

Example of what I need to convert

```
public virtual ObjectResult<string> GetTransData(string iN_MEM_ID)
    {
        var iN_MEM_IDParameter = iN_MEM_ID != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("IN_MEM_ID", iN_MEM_ID) :
            new ObjectParameter("IN_MEM_ID", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<string>("GetTransData", iN_MEM_IDParameter);
    }
```

Typically I will create a file of dbcontext like this

```
public Clinical_CaseTrakker_Context(DbContextOptions<Clinical_CaseTrakker_Context> options) : base(options)
    { }
```

Then I do dbset like

```
 public DbSet<USP_Get_SAI> USP_Get_SAIs { get; set; }
```

But this whole `ObjectResult<T>` I never worked with

Normally I will just call a stored proc like this

```
List<OfflineMember> offLine = await _CaseTrakker_Context.OfflineMembers.FromSql("EXECUTE CT.usp_Get_SAI_Offline_Members {0}", userId).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you use [FromSqlRaw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql)?

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogs")
    .ToList();
```

> FromSqlRaw allows you to use named parameters in the SQL query string, which is useful when a stored procedure has optional parameters:
>
> ```
> var user = new SqlParameter("user", "johndoe");
>
> var blogs = context.Blogs
>     .FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser @filterByUser=@user", user)
>     .ToList();
> ```

Comment: should i just skip using the ObjectResult and build a method that essentially does the same thing ?

Comment: I think rebuilding sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

EF Core still supports the syntax below with the minor change below to Task<>:

```
Task<List<OfflineMember>> offLine = await _CaseTrakker_Context.OfflineMembers.FromSql("EXECUTE CT.usp_Get_SAI_Offline_Members {0}", userId).ToListAsync();
```

OR

```
List<OfflineMember> offLine = _CaseTrakker_Context.OfflineMembers.FromSql("EXECUTE CT.usp_Get_SAI_Offline_Members {0}", userId).ToList();
```

Comment: Should I just not worry about the ObjectResult,  and just build my own method ?